# Google maps info window or tooltip

Tags: google-maps

I am having hard time getting a simple code or explanation how can I change the background of the tool tip to black and of course change the text color to white.

Here's where you can see the map: http://adventurebar.staging.wpengine.com/the-escapologist/

Please help me !

I need a simple css or JavaScript without anything to add or install as I am using page builder with google maps plugin

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the color in the page builder google maps plugin. Take a look at this web page for advanced map formatting: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=de

Regards

Max

Comment: Thanks. But I am referring to the tooltip and not the map itself since I already changed that.